# useEffect with a dependency that changes too fast

Tags: reactjs, use-effect, use-state, use-ref

Here's the problem:

```
function Foo(){
  let [events, setEvents] = useState([])

  useEffect(() => {
    let subscription = client.subscribe("eventType", event => {
      setEvents([...events, event])
    })
    return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
  }, [events])
}
```

So here if I make events a useEffect dependency it will unsubscribe / subscribe every time an event is added, and I will miss some. I can make events a ref, but then it won't re-render.

What's the right way to do this?

**Edit:** From the comments / answers I've gotten so far there seems to be no good way to deal with this in React. I have an ugly setInterval solution that I will post as an answer if nobody comes up with something better within 2 days.

**EDIT 2:** Here's a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-rubin-87hz6p?file=/src/App.js) showing the issue with setInterval. I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require events as a dependency (removing events dependency is not a solution, obviously.)

Comment: Why does `events` need to be a dependency?

Comment: Because otherwise it's always empty

Comment: Please clarify, what do you want to achieve? And what are your concerns or problems?

Comment: It appears that you are pushing events every time client emits an event EventType. Are you handling removal of events from state.

Comment: @Alpesh, thanks but that's not really the issue I'm having. It feels like setting state to a dependency in useEffect is probably an anti-pattern, and I'm hoping someone smarter than I am will weigh in. I appreciate your comments / effort though.

Comment: What's the expected behavior?

Comment: The expected behavior is that I have to choose between missing events or not re-rendering when I need it it to. The desired behavior is that I don't. I'm looking for a solution to this even if it means ditching React for a different framework.

Comment: If you are observing performance issues resulting into missed events or slow rendering, it might be because JS engine stays busy subscribing & unsubscribing the events. Since you're only adding new events and retaining all old ones, it makes sense to not to execute unsubscribe and subscribe for all existing events but instead only subscribe to the new event.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). The information you have provided does not demonstrate a problem—however, it seems like you are experiencing a problem based on your comments. You should update the question according to the criteria in the preceding links in this comment.

Comment: @pguardiario A codesandbox link is not a substitute for updating the question, and external URLs can break. SO is designed to be a persistent resource. Please update your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of grabbing `events` from outside the `useEffect`, you can just [pass a callback to `setEvents` that will receive the current value for `events`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates):

```
function Foo(){
    let [events, setEvents] = useState([])

    useEffect(() => {
        let subscription = client.subscribe("eventType", event => {
            setEvents((previousEvents) => [...previousEvents, event])
        })
        return () => subscription.unsubscribe()
    }, []) // no need to add `events` to dependencies because we're getting it from `setEvent`'s callback
}
```

Comment: Removing the dependency is not the solution, sorry.

Comment: @pguardiario What about it is "not the solution"? This is idiomatic React, and using the functional argument to "setState" guarantees that the latest state is used at the time it is set without needing to include it as a dependency.

Comment: @pguardiario By using this solution you're not removing the dependency. When you use functional updates what happens is that React makes sure to call your callback with the current value for your state. That's exactly why you don't need to add the dependency, because you're not using an external variable, you're using a value that React will pass when calling your callback.

Comment: @pguardiario I don't know if that was clear, but if it wasn't please refer to the documentation I linked. This is the only solution that you got. You need to remove your `events` dependency because if you don't every time `events` is updated your useEffect will run your cleanup function.

Comment: @asla03 - yes you're right. Thanks for the clarification.